# how to set security rules to prevent updating of data by other users in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am new in firebase I want to know how to set security rules to prevent updating of data by other users in firebase.
I working on a blog app where user can login and write their blogs and I want to prevent the user to do not update or delete another users blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on the structure of your app. You can also create a `function` inside the firestore rules, here's one example:

```
match /blog/{blogId} {
   allow update, delete: if isBlogOwner();
   function isBlogOwner() {
      return request.auth.uid == resource.data.author;
   }
}
```

It allows to update or delete a blog if he / she is the blog owner. If you want to know more visit this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query).